# What is a non-procedural algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I have heard a term "procedural algorithm" before so I'm curious what would constitute a non-procedural algorithm? Are there any examples?

As far as I understand, there are maze generation algorithms that generate mazes procedurally - randomly or pseudo randomly using a seed value of some kind. The opposite of that would be making a maze manually by hand but that wouldn't equal to using an algorithm any longer so I'm a bit confused on this topic.

Any sources, links to examples are welcome.

Comment: Some context is missing here. Where did you find this phrase?

Comment: I know the concept of procedural programming, which is a programming paradigm based on procedure calls. One of the major languages for procedural programming is C. On the other hand, programming languages that rely on classes are known as object-oriented programming languages.

Comment: I take *procedural algorithm* to be a [pleonasm](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pleonasm). Then, there is non-procedural programming/coding, e.g. [declarative programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming).